# Calling IEnumerable<T> ToList() at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a `IEnumerable<Person>` for example.

I want to be able to make it `List<Person>` at runtime

I have the below code but errors saying I can't convert System Runtime type

Is there something I'm missing?

```
private static readonly MethodInfo enumerableToListMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToList", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

//genericType will be Person
var genericType = modelType.GetGenericArguments().First();

var genericToListMethod = enumerableToListMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { genericType });

//modelType is IEnumerable<Person>
var ienumtype = genericToListMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { modelType });

Activator.CreateInstance(ienumtype.GetType());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've gotta pass in the IEnumerable to the invoke, NOT the type of the enumerable - also, calling invoke will return the List, not a Type.

put in code:

```
var instance = < the IEnumerable >;
var modelType = instance.GetType();

//modelType is IEnumerable<Person>
var enumerableAsList = genericToListMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { instance});
```

Based on your comments, I'm guessing you're after something more like this:

```
Func<IEnumerable<T>, List<T>> MakeMeAToListerForEnumerablesOfType<T>()
{
    var itemType = typeof(T);
    var enumerableToListMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToList", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
    var genericToListMethod = enumerableToListMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { itemType });
    return (Func<IEnumerable<T>, List<T>>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<IEnumerable<T>, List<T>>), genericToListMethod);
}
```

Which you would call like:

```
IEnumerable<string> enumerable = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };
var toLister = MakeMeAToListerForEnumerablesOfType<string>();
```

Derp. Missed the call...

```
var enumerableAsList = toLister(enumerable);
```

Comment: makes sense however I dont have the instance at this point. back to the drawing board

Comment: just the types unfortunately

Comment: I could hard code it and return new List<genericType>() somehow but I'm not sure that would compile

Comment: I got it working with this:   var genericType = modelType.GetGenericArguments().First();

                    var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(genericType);
                    
                    return Activator.CreateInstance(listType);

Comment: That sounds like you're just creating a List<T> where T is the modelType - you're not actually ToList()'ing the original enumerable...did I misread your original question?

Comment: no, doing ToList or creating a new list is the same result for me

Comment: Ah, well - your solution should be just fine, then.

Comment: @JerKimball doesn't ToList creates a new list ?

Comment: @Jon Tolist does create a new list.

Comment: @RoyiNamir True, but I think he was after just creating an empty instance of the typed list, not necc. calling ToList on it